# Is it possible to run multi applications at Android Things?

Tags: android-things

Is it possible to run multi applications at Android Things as Android OS?

For example, we can run `facebook` and `Instagram` simultaneously at Android OS. Can we run app1 & app2 simultaneously at Android Things ?

Comment: Do you think that `Android` (`not AndroidThings`) can run multi apps simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Things automatically launches **exactly one activity** containing the [IOT_LAUNCHER](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html#home_activity_support) intent filter. The app containing this activity will be in the foreground state.

Additional apps can be launched by the system via the [BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) broadcast intent. These apps will be in the background state.

Of course, your code may also launch additional activities and services in other apps as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks @Devunwired. Is Android Things designed to run multi-apps at the same time (one at foreground, others at background)? Do we have any user case for multi-apps run at one IoT device ?

Comment: Yes, Android Things manages apps the same way as any Android device, so you can architect your solution in whatever manner best fits your use case.

Comment: Great. Thanks @Devunwired.

Comment: Answer is unclear. For example, I flashed my device with a sample app that uses GPIO (say P1). Then I took another sample app and flashed that as well, for which I'm forced to use another GPIO pin P2 since first app continues to use P1. In fact, I was able to use both apps and both contained IOT_LAUNCHER.

Comment: @arvindpdmn Standard Android rules apply here. If you want to share a resource like a GPIO pin between two apps, you need to close that resource from one app when it goes into the background (e.g. `onPause`) so it can be opened from the other app. The samples assume only one app running at a time, so this code is found in `onDestroy`, which wouldn't be called if the activity is still active in the background.

Comment: I assume that ContentProvider to talk to the shared GPIO pin would be way to go for coder.in.me and expose its functionality.
@Devunwired can AndroidThings provide such shared (content provider like) based functionality, or that is too slow.